# cómo guardar el mismo valor para diferentes usuarios y evitar que cada uno guarde por duplicado

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla donde los usuarios pueden registrar múltiples productos, lo que quiero es que cada usuario pueda guardar productos  de un determinado campo con valores iguales a los productos de otros usuarios pero evitar que los usuarios  guarden valores duplicados para sí mismos.

Lo que he hecho hasta ahora en mi código solo puede evitar que todos los usuarios guarden valores duplicados.

```
 if(!empty($_POST)){
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];


$cod_excurssao = $_POST['cod_excurssao'];
$tipo_quarto = $_POST['tipo_quarto'];
$num_quarto = $_POST['num_quarto'];
$valor_diaria = $_POST['valor_diaria'];


if(isNullquarto($num_quarto, $valor_diaria)){

    echo "Deve preencher todos os campos por favor!";


}else{

      if(quartoExiste($num_quarto)){
        echo "Já existe um quarto com este numero: $num_quarto";
      }else{

          $sql = "INSERT INTO tipo_quarto ( cod_excurssao, tipo_quarto, num_quarto, valor_diaria) VALUES ( $cod_excurssao, $tipo_quarto, $num_quarto, $valor_diaria)";
          $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
          if($resultado){
                 header("Location: registro_quartos.php");
          }else{
           echo "Erro ao guardar";
          }//3-else
        } //2-else
      }//1-else
     }//empty post      
    ?>
```

Esta é a função

```
    //verifica si existe registro para quarto
function quartoExiste($num_quarto)
{
    global $mysqli;

    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT num_quarto FROM tipo_quarto WHERE  num_quarto = ?   LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $num_quarto);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    if ($num > 0){
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;   
    }
}

    ==================================================

    //verifica si campos são nulos

    function isNullquarto($num_quarto, $valor_diaria){
    if(strlen(trim($num_quarto)) < 1 || strlen(trim($valor_diaria)) < 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es algo más propio de la base de datos que de PHP. En el diseño de las tablas pondrías restricciones en las que un mismo `id_usuario`. no  tenga más de una vez un `id_producto`. Por PHP luego verificarías si esa condición de cumple. Si lo haces sólo por PHP, aunque funcione, habría un mal diseño en tus tablas.

Comment: @A. Cedano gracias por tu  orientación, ahora tengo algo con lo que guiarme, a un que no se como empezar

Comment: Es que tu duda es más sobre el modelo de datos (base de datos) que sobre PHP. No haces nada con programarlo en PHP si el modelo de datos está mal. Cuando diseñas las tablas hay restricciones de unicidad que debes indicar para decirle al manejador: *no me aceptes más de un registro donde se repitan estos valores*. En esas restricciones de unicidad puedes indicar una o varias columnas. Dependiendo del manejador, deberías revisar las restricciones en la documentación para que sepas como funciona la restricción `UNIQUE`.

Comment: A. Cedano , estaba estudiando lo que me digistes de restriciones UNIQUE, pero para lo que quiero hacer no me vale ya que la restricción UNIQUE identifica de manera única a cada fila de una tabla. Puedo haber varias restricciones UNIQUE en diferentes columnas de una tabla, pero eso no me dejaria insertar valore iguales para  registro de diferentes usuário.

Comment: Hay restricciones que combinan varias columnas, por ejemplo `UNIQUE (id_usuario, id_ciudad)` controlaría que no haya dos veces el mismo usuario y la misma ciudad, permitiendo sin embargo que un mismo usuario esté en varias ciudades. Según entendí era algo así lo que querías. Repito, aunque lo hayas logrado por programación, deberías definirlo también en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui hacerlo da la forma que queria. Lo que he hecho es quitar la función de quartoExiste, despues antes del insert he puesto un select donde verifica si existe el mismo valor en el campo $cod_excurssao y $num_quarto.

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    require 'funcs/conexion.php';
    require 'funcs/funcs.php';


    if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    }


    if(!empty($_POST)){
    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];


    $cod_excurssao= $_POST['cod_excurssao'];
    $tipo_quarto = $_POST['tipo_quarto'];
    $num_quarto = $_POST['num_quarto'];
    $valor_diaria = $_POST['valor_diaria'];


    if(isNullquarto($num_quarto, $valor_diaria)){

        echo "Deve preencher todos os campos por favor!";


    }else{

          $sql="SELECT * FROM tipo_quarto WHERE cod_excurssao='$cod_excurssao' AND num_quarto ='$num_quarto' ";
            $resultado1=$mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);

          if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado1)>0) {

            echo "Já existe um quarto com este numero: $num_quarto";

          }else{

              $sql = "INSERT INTO tipo_quarto ( cod_excurssao, tipo_quarto, num_quarto, valor_diaria) VALUES ( $cod_excurssao, $tipo_quarto, $num_quarto, $valor_diaria)";
              $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql);

              if($resultado2){
                     header("Location: registro_quartos.php");
              }else{
               echo "Erro ao guardar";
              }//3-else
          } //2-else
    }//1-elseif
  }//empty post     
?>
```